# Socket Accept long waiting time

Tags: c#, vb.net, sockets, websocket

My "server" is accepting incoming requests with:

```
 clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept()
 ' Socket Information
  Dim clientInfo As IPEndPoint = CType(clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint, IPEndPoint)
            Dim serverInfo As IPEndPoint = CType(serverSocket.LocalEndPoint, IPEndPoint)

            ' Set Thread for each Web Browser Connection
            clientThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf ProcessRequest))

            clientThread.Start()
```

In that thread i am handling all the different requests.
The clients sends the request with:

```
Dim request As WebRequest
    request = WebRequest.Create("http://" + hostName + ":" + serverPort + "/")
    request.Method = "GET"
    Dim response = request.GetResponse
```

that works all fine and sends the response within 10 ms back to the client, but sometimes i am experiencing a long accepting time between the  `Dim response = request.GetResponse` and the `clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept()`.
This time is about 2 seconds on Windows 10!!!
(On an Windows 7 pc i got waiting times about 1 second.)

I am experiencing this issue mostly at the first call from a new Process. Than it works fine, but random it waits again for 2 seconds.

Edit:
When i disconnect the network and work with localhost it is the same issue. So it is not a  network problem. Maybe a memory issue?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: is it an IP address or a name? It might be doing a DNS lookup or something like that

Comment: Without knowing exact environmental details or how any of this is hosted, would think it's not completely unreasonable to expect there to be some delay on the first call as resources are allocated, and routes resolved etc.  The fact that you're seeing different delays on different machines though suggests this probably more an environmental issue rather than straight coding so might almost be better to check the SuperUsers stack

Comment: @user253751 i am using ip addresses and names, like localhost.